# Split string by character and keep before and after string

Tags: excel, vba, string, split

I have string containing numbers. These numbers are coordinates for scientific modeling.

I need to split this string by character "-" to partial string "before" and "after".

This works only for static number of digit (character).

```
Dim str As String
Dim before As String
Dim after As String

str = "3-525"
before= Left(str, InStr(str, "-") - 1) ' =3
after= Right(str, InStr(str, "-") + 1) ' =525
```

If input is `str = "3-525"`  output is `before = 3` and `after = 525`
But when it comes to `str = "15-50"` output is `before = 15` and `after = 5-50` and is annoying to retype it again and again.

I need some dynamic solution to split these coordinates by "-" character.

Comment: Added a late answer in addition to @BigBen 's valid answer trying to explain the (simple) background of your issue for a better understanding; feel free to upvote if helpful :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function):

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim str As String
    str = "3-525"
    
    Dim x
    x = Split(str, "-")
    
    Debug.Print x(0) '<--- this is "before", or 3
    Debug.Print x(1) '<--- this is "after", or 525
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course applying `Split()` is the most evident way to execute a *split* operation. -
Nevertheless your original code logic to count from an `Instr()` finding isn't wrong *per se* and you need not reject the way you form the `after` variable completely.

(1) Using the `Right()` function only needs a **length** as further argument, not a *position*. So you might calculate the remaining length to the right as difference between the total length and the `"-"` character and modify your code to

```
 after = Right(s, Len(s) - InStr(s, "-"))
```

*(btw I'd prefer `s` to your `str` variable as I don't want to mix it up with VBA's  `Str()` function)*.

(2) Alternatively you could use the `Mid()` function and code as follows:

```
 after = Mid(s, InStr(s, "-") + 1)
```

*Here it suffices to pass a starting position as further argument (without need to indicate a total lenght in addition).*